# trying to add line(array of string) between specific lines in text file by java program?

Tags: java, arrays, string, filewriter

I am trying to write program by seeing from various forums.
Programs as bellow, aiming to add line after 3rd line of existing txt file, but before 5th line. & i trying to keeping previous lines safely when i will see completion of execution of this program, but i failed to enter line between 3 & 5. It add below 5th line.
If this basic program works then i will try to add 'array of string' in file between line 3 & 5 like

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;  
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileReader;  
import java.io.FileWriter;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.LineNumberReader;  

public class WriteToFileExample {  

    /** 
     * @param args 
     */  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
String content = "This is the content to write into file by Mandar";  
File file = new File("/example/mandar.txt");  
if(!file.exists()){  
    try {  
        file.createNewFile();  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
    try {  
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);  
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);  
        bw.write(content);  
        bw.newLine();  
        bw.close();  
        System.out.println("Done");  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  


}else{  
    try {  
        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(file));  
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);  
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);  
        lnr.setLineNumber(6);  
        for(int i =1; i<lnr.getLineNumber();i++){  
//          System.out.println("for = "+i);  
//          bw.newLine();  
            if(i == 3){  
                System.out.println("4");  
                bw.write(content);  
//              bw.newLine();  
            }  
        }  
        bw.close();  
        System.out.println("Done1");  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
}  
    }  

}
```

Please help me. I am not getting any clue or idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `lnr.setLineNumber(6)` to set the `lnr` to write to line 6. Your `for` loop simply loops from 1 to 6 and writes the content **at line 6** when `i==3`. I haven't tested this yet, but try using `lnr.setLineNumber(4)` and getting rid of your for loop.

Comment: Thanks dr3wmurphy, i try lnr.setLineNumber(4) as you say, but still i got result like in mandar.txt 1 2 3 one bellow the other, after 3 i keep blank space & then 5. File complete. Now by program i always get result that string content after 5. not between 3 & 5.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks javabreakpoint,
 I tried my scenario with your way as follows

```
import java.io.*;

public class JInsert {
 public static void main(String args[]){
 try {
   JInsert j = new JInsert();
   File file = new File("/example/mandar.txt");
   j.insertStringInFile(file, 4, "4");
  // j.insertStringInFile(file,Integer.parseInt(args[1]), args[2]);
   }
 catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }

 public void insertStringInFile
     (File inFile, int lineno, String lineToBeInserted) 
   throws Exception {
 // temp file
 File outFile = new File("/example/$$$$$$$$.tmp");

 // input
 FileInputStream fis  = new FileInputStream(inFile);
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
     (new InputStreamReader(fis));

 // output         
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fos);

 String thisLine = "";
 int i =1;
 while ((thisLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
   if(i == lineno) out.println(lineToBeInserted);
   out.println(thisLine);
   i++;
   }
out.flush();
out.close();
in.close();

inFile.delete();
outFile.renameTo(inFile);
}
}
```

But 1 new problem i seen that in file mandar.txt which expected as follows before run the above program.

```
1
2
3

5
```

What if mandar.txt modified before run the above program as follows:-

```
1

2
3
5
```

means now blank line changes to between 1 & 2 but we(human) know that string "4" should enter between 3 & 5. But now program add line at line no 4 but now we can see mandar.txt as follows

```
 1

 2
 4
 3
 5
```

**How to secure that any time whether 3 & 5 at any line number then my string enter between them?**
means i will get 2 ways in program
1. line number
2. line content securely insert where it should be insert.